# Which is correct — "email me [on/at] x@y.com"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, collocation, email

Which variant is the correct one:

> - email me on xxx@xxx.com
> - email me at xxx@xxx.com
> - email me to xxx@xxx.com

Or should another preposition go there?

Comment: Consider the archeological equivalent, "Please mail me at 10 Main St, Smithtown."  Clearly "on" and "to" don't fit.  However, "Send mail *to* 10 Main St..." works.

Comment: Welcome aboard. You might also try a visit to [ell.se].

Answer (score 5):

In American English we always say email me *at*.

I think it's fairly arbitrary but, it agrees with the terminology set forth by the @(at) symbol itself.

I believe this was chosen due to the original email addresses being held on servers owned by companies and universities. If you were John who worked for IBM, you could be referred to as John at IBM. Hence John@IBM.com.

These virtual addresses also borrow from terminology from physical and other electronic addresses.

Physical addresses are usually denoted as at. I'm at 473 Main Street. But you can send mail *to* 473 Main Street.

Telephone usage is likewise ambiguous in this. You can say:  I can be reached at (123)456-7890. Or you can say, I can be reached on Ext. 473.   In this case it seems to be differentiated by whether or not you are using an extension or line vs the phone number.

Comment: I don't think so -- I think the "@" followed the "at" usage per my archaeology comment above.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I edited to clarify I meant agrees with.

Comment: Additionally, I believe it has to do with the original purpose of email. I will expand my answer.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I've edited and expanded upon your correct statement. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with you in general, but as you *hint*, you could also use *to* when coupled with *send*, as in *send it **to** abc@def.com*; but *send it to me **at** abc@def.com*.

Comment: @bib Yes.  I agree with that statement.  But, in general terms, you would construct it as *email me at*  I think the *to* is more a function of agreeing with *send* in that case.

Comment: @DavidM Agreed, *send to* is a phrasal verb.